# How to match a file property against entire array in powershell

Tags: arrays, shell, powershell

I have question and a problem.

I have a list of 600,000 FLV files, which are the videos I want to keep.
I have a folder of 5 million FLV files, and I want to delete the 4.4 million or so that I do not need.

I've been playing with this problem for hours but cant find anything easy considering arrays are immutable.

I was thinking of doing:
foreach file in the 6 million folder list, check to see if the name property matches any item in the array of files I want to keep (using import-csv) AND if the date is more than 30 days old.

The date part is easy, but I am not sure how to compare the name against the array.  Is it really as easy as just referencing the entire array?  I'm not sure what powershell would do.  I will be continuing to try to do this but I would appreciate anyone's help / input on how to do this or a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PowerShell, if you have a file with the filenames to keep at C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt and the files are at C:\FLVLocation\ something like this would work.

```
$keep = Get-Content C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt
Get-ChildItem C:\FLVLocation| 
    where{$keep -notcontains $_.Name -and $_.CreationTime -lt [DateTime]::Now.Date.AddDays(-30)}| 
    Remove-Item
```

But please, test first.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not instead move all the files you want to keep.

Iterate over all the files in the array and if the dat is ok, move the file to a "keep" folder. Delete the rest and then move the files back from the "keep" folder.

Probably good to do a "dry run" first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I was not able to do this, intially, as  it was taking all but 3 gigs on a 2 terabyte drive.  I've been able to use the length property to kill ovff about a million small files (obviously too small to be a normal, not corrupted/early terminated submission).  I got 60 gigs free now, so I might just do that.

Comment: Would there be a way to take the CSV list of files I want to keep, create a CSV list of files on the server, and then basically subtract the first from the second?

I know they're immutable, but I was thinking maybe if I create a third container array, and anything in the CSV of ALL my files that does NOT match a file name in the first CSV of files to keep, to add that file name to a third array.  The idea then would be to just delete files with file names contained in the third array

I know they are immutable, but would I be able to take, like:

Comment: @Matt Wall Move should not take up any more space.

Comment: Maybe you could do this 'diff list_all_files list_keep_files| grep -e "^<" | cut -b3-'

Comment: dur I was thinking of copy item.. so glad for your input